# Iterate ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have more then one property I need to grab, that starts with the same prefix but I can only get the exact value by key for `ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider`.  Is there a way to grab multiple ValueProviders or iterate the `System.Web.Mvc.DictionaryValueProvider<object>`?

```
 var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
```

The reason for doing this is a dynamic property called Settings which will bind to json properties below.  Right now there is no property called "Enable" on Settings so it doesnt bind normally.

```
public class Integration
{
      public dynamic Settings {get;set;}
}

"Integrations[0].Settings.Enable": "true"
"Integrations[0].Settings.Name": "Will"
```

Comment: What's the outcome you're trying to achieve?  Why will a list not work?

Comment: I updated the post with that information.

Comment: First I would ask why is it necessary to make this a dynamic property?  Seems like you're overcomplicating something simple as passing settings along which could be done easily with a viewModel with all of your settings.

Comment: Because it comes from dynamic views, so I dont know which Integration has the different properties, so no its not overcomplicating, its a legit setup.

Comment: Have to agree with @Mocolicious. It seems you have an x-y issue. What are you doing in the view that generates this json. And why are you sending it as json? If your view is for generating a series of property name/value pairs, then it would be far easier to bind to a (say) `List<Setting> Settings` where `Setting` contains properties for the `Name` and `Value`

Comment: I have done that in the past with name/value, but these are strongly typed views and I want to keep it that way.

Comment: Geez? Using a `List<Setting>` will be strong typed!

Comment: string typed is not strongly typed, what the heck man?

Comment: @MikeFlynn You already asked this question. This isn't a JSON string. JSON *dictionaries* would handle your scenario just fine without requiring such complex code. BTW I didn't downvote before, I won't downvote now. You'll have to consider though that if *everyone* warns you that you are doing it wrong, maybe it's not *everyone else* that's wrong.

Comment: @MikeFlynn why don't you use a JSON string for key/value pairs? Why not `Settings: { "Enabled":"true", "Name" : "Will"}`? You can deserialize this into a real strongly-typed object, or to a `Dictionary<string,string>` or to a `dynamic` object with `JsonConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>`. Web API already uses JSON.NET so all you need to do is specify the desired parameter type

Comment: I found the solution myself guys, hope you learned something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
 public class DynamicPropertyBinder : PropertyBinderAttribute
    {
        public override bool BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(Object))
            {
                foreach(var valueProvider in bindingContext.ValueProvider as System.Collections.IList)
                {
                    var dictionary = valueProvider as DictionaryValueProvider<object>;

                    if (dictionary != null)
                    {
                        var keys = dictionary.GetKeysFromPrefix($"{bindingContext.ModelName}.{propertyDescriptor.Name}");

                        if (keys.Any())
                        {
                            var expando = new ExpandoObject();

                            foreach (var key in keys)
                            {
                                var keyValue = dictionary.GetValue(key.Value);

                                if (keyValue != null)
                                {
                                    AddProperty(expando, key.Key, keyValue.RawValue);

                                }
                            }

                            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, expando);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            else
                expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I will post the solution that I've found.

You can get all submitted keys from the request object, and then iterating over them get the actual values:

```
var keys = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.ToList();

foreach (var key in keys)
{
    var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).AttemptedValue;
}
```